# Registering script for event validation from within the JS file

Tags: javascript, c#

Just a quick question here. I am trying to register a js file for script validation using

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("strIncludeJSFile")) Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(strIncludeJSFile.GetType(), "strIncludeJSFile", strIncludeJSFile);
```

code in C# and it works well for the js files. But, some js files are used in multiple pages, so I am unsure if the above code will be a good idea. As such, I want to do the same thing in the js file itself, instead of using the code behind. Is there any possibility to do that? Or is this thing specific to C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can register a js file (or script block) from html by using a `script` tag. However, the main reason `RegisterClientScriptBlock` exists is because developers might need to generate (or modify) a script block dynamically from code behind or conditionally register a script file dynamically.

If you need any of the above...generate a script block dynamically, then you "might" be better off registering it from code behind, I mean, it depends on the whole solution itself, it's hard to recommend an approach without having some context. Either way, some options are:

1. register the script blocks from code behind if you need to generate based on some conditions that can only be evaluated from server side code
2. use a master page for better and register the script block from the master page. This will make it easier to maintain if you keep the logic in one place
3. similar to the option above, you can use a base page class if using a master page is not possible
4. use an html `script` element if what you need is to reference a static js file
5. use place holders such as js variables and fetch dynamic data from the server using ajax
6. use unobtrusive javascript, custom data attributes and ajax

Whatever the suitable option(s) is depends on too many factor that you have to assess

Comment: Thanks. So, I can simply do the same thing as I do for normal inline scripts? 

Also, I am trying to add a script from within the page load function, but that doesn't work somehow. So, I thought, I will give this method a try.

Comment: @jitendragarg "doesn't work" is a pretty broad term...there's no reason why registering a script block on page load should not work. However, usually, it is recommended to register script blocks at a later stage of the page lifecycle such as `OnPreRender`...especially if you need to query server controls that might change value during a request

Comment: Doesn't work, in the sense, it still fails event validation. In code, I have a binddropdown function. that function adds the values to the dropdown. So, I register the script just before that. But, the postback still fails.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I am dumb. I think I should register the binddropdown function (c# function in same class as page_load event handler). JS is probably working fine, but I won't know as binddropdown function might be failing event validation.